# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'imdata'

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Trying to retrieve some fields from the returned JSON:

```
Event [{'subscriptionId': ['72059810266873859'], 'imdata': [{'fvAEPg': {'attributes': {'annotation': '', 'childAction': '', 'configIssues': '', 'configSt': 'applied', 'descr': '', 'dn': 'uni/tn-Student1/ap-AP_SD1/epg-er34', 'exceptionTag': '', 'extMngdBy': '', 'floodOnEncap': 'disabled', 'fwdCtrl': '', 'hasMcastSource': 'no', 'isAttrBasedEPg': 'no', 'isSharedSrvMsiteEPg': 'no', 'lcOwn': 'local', 'matchT': 'AtleastOne', 'modTs': '2020-05-01T22:31:30.293+01:00', 'monPolDn': 'uni/tn-common/monepg-default', 'name': 'er34', 'nameAlias': '', 'pcEnfPref': 'unenforced', 'pcTag': 'any', 'prefGrMemb': 'exclude', 'prio': 'unspecified', 'rn': '', 'scope': '3047425', 'shutdown': 'no', 'status': 'created', 'triggerSt': 'not_triggerable', 'txId': '6341068275364643083', 'uid': '15374'}}}]}]
```

using this function im receiving the json and using pyjq:

```
def printws():
    while True:
        message = pyjq.all((ws.recv()))
        print("Event", message)
        wbxt_api.messages.create(room_id, text=(message[0].imdata))
```

the message is printed as above but im tring to get only some of the fields and get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "aci_teste_new161.py", line 180, in printws
    wbxt_api.messages.create(room_id, text=(message[0].imdata))
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'imdata'
```

It should be related to trying to access the dict value, im pretty junior on python and i don't seem to get it working...

another way:

```
def printws():
    while True:
        print((ws.recv()(["imdata"][0]["fvAEPg"]["attributes"]["name"])))

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "aci_teste_new161.py", line 190, in printws
    print((ws.recv()(["imdata"][0]["fvAEPg"]["attributes"]["name"])))
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

any help?

Comment: To access dictionary value, you should use `['imdata']` (`__gteitem__`), `message[0].imdata` -> `message[0]['imdata']`

Comment: TypeError: We were expecting to receive an instance of one of the following types: 'basestring'or 'None'; but instead we received [{'fvAEPg': {'attributes': {'childAction': '', 'dn': 'uni/tn-Student1/ap-AP_SD1/epg-jj', 'modTs': '2020-05-01T23:15:29.345+01:00', 'pcTag': 'any', 'rn': '', 'scope': '0', 'status': 'deleted'}}}] which is a 'list'.

Comment: working:    print("Event", message[0]['imdata'][0]['fvAEPg']['attributes']['dn'])

Comment: thanks! if i need to access different dicts (from the one above fvAEPg) how can i skip that one and get "attributes" and "dn" for the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access python dictionary data follow this,

```py
message[0]["imdata"]
```

### Edit

To get unknown keys in your dictionary you can do this,

```py
imdata = message[0]['imdata'][0]
imdata_keys = list(imdata.keys())
```

This will give you a list of *keys* in your dictionary.
There is only one key into your imdata so this will return you,

```py
['fvAEPg']
```

Now if you want to access `fvAEPg -> attributes -> dn` you can follow the procedure bellow:

```py
imdata[imdata_keys[0]]['attributes']['dn']
```

*Happy codding ;)*

Comment: im using this one for acess the"dn" attribute -----      message[0]['imdata'][0]['fvAEPg']['attributes']['dn']  however because the returned json can have diferent values in the "fvAEPg" field i need to have a way to match all the returned values...any thoughts? like can i have a regular expression to match any value in that field?

Comment: I have edited my answer explained everything that you need.